# R program for classification of WhatsApp data

Tags: rstudio

My project is based on Analysis. I can't figure out the Classification Algorithm in R to deal with the WhatsApp Data.

It would be of great help if you help me with this problem.

Comment: What does your data look like? What are you trying to classify?

Comment: I want to analyze the WhatsApp data using classification Algo( the WhatsApp data is in the txt format and we get it by 'Email Chat' option in WhatsApp)